# How to show that convex polytope is not a Voronoi cell?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convex-polytopes

Given a combinatorial type of a convex polytope, what techniques are available for showing that it **cannot** be realized as a Voronoi cell of some point system?

Comment: A pity about the whole giant insect thing.

Comment: Pardon my naivete, but if pick a point inside the polytope and reflect it across every facets, isn't your polytope the voronoi cell of that point?

Can you give an example of a convex polytope that isn't? 

Comment: Voronoi cells of lattices are quite restricted. Did you mean that instead?

Comment: @Arthur B: You are absolutely right, of course. I am mildly shocked by this false belief I carried with me for a long time, and how easily it could be refuted. Since I am normally not working with Voronoi diagrams, I never questioned it. A couple of days ago I decided to try out MO and thought, well, this would make for an interesting question... but apparently not. So thanks for your comment!

Comment: posted as and answer then

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Every (non-flat) convex polytope is the Voronoi cell of a point in a set of points. Constructive proof: pick a point inside the polytope, and build its symmetric reflection along every facet of the polytope.

Answer (score 1):

There is this paper of [Boissonnat and Karavelas](http://www.tem.uoc.gr/~mkaravel/files/papers/apcell.pdf) where they prove bounds on the combinatorial convexity of Voronoi cells. Presumably if your polytope does not satisfy the bound, it is not a Voronoi cell..

Comment: Of course, the bound has to depend on the number of points, so I don't see how this can work. (From skimming the paper, it appears that the best bound is Theta(n^ceiling(d/2)), where n is the number of points and d is the dimensionality of space, which is not unexpected.) 